# Box Slider Styling

Tags: html, css, slider

I am creating a slider with the bxslider plugin, the slideshow itself is working well, however there is a mighty big gap between the slider and the pager (or the navigation), I would have thought this was a css problem however I have been through and through my stylesheet and can come across nothing which would cause this problem. Below are several of the javascript links and some additional code -

```
<script src="http://bxslider.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/js/rainbow.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/js/scripts.js"></script>

.slider {   
    width:100%;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
.bxslider {
    width:100%; height:245px;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

.bx-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    *zoom:1;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    position:absolute; 
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
    display:inline-block;
    *zoom:1; margin:0; padding:0;
    *display:inline; background:blue;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {    margin:0; padding:0;
    background:#c1c1c1;
    margin:0 10px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    display: block;
    width:14px; height:14px;
    border-radius:50px;
    -moz-border-radius:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover {
    cursor:pointer; 
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
    background:#7cceee;
    margin:0 10px;  
    width:14px; height:14px;
    outline:0;
    border-radius:50px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
}
```

I know this is probably quite a simple question, but annoying none the less. Hope you guys can help.

Thanks guys!

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle please?

Comment: I do however the plugin uses several links, I can paste them into my original question though. Thanks!

Comment: We need to see your markup before anyone can suggest a solution. Can you add a link to your development site?

Answer (score 0):

Have found the solution, it was indeed in the styling, amended code is below -

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    position: absolute;
bottom:50px; /* this is the important */ 
width: 100%;
}
```